# OptionButton determines value then use in macro

Tags: excel, vba, userform

A basic simple VBA question that I havent been able to work out even though there are numerous tutorials about it.

I want a Userform to pop-up, give you two options (OptionButton1 and OptionButton2). You choose one, click ok. And depending on what Option is chosen a certain value is used (in an email, for which I DID finish the macro). For simplifying purposes i now just want the variable 'contents' to be printed in cell A1.

I have these parts so far:

```
Sub MailOption()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then Var1 = "Text example 1"
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
If OptionButton2.Value = True Then Var1 = "Text example 2"
End Sub

Private Sub SendEmail_Click()
Cells(1, 1).Value = Var1
End Sub
```

There are multiple problems: the variable is not shown in Cell A1 and when i press Send Email the Form is not closed. I am probably doing lots of stuff wrong but its the first time im using a userform. Ty very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use this one without handling `OptionButton_Click`:

```
Private Sub SendEmail_Click()
    Dim res As String
    If OptionButton1.Value Then
        res = "Text example 1"
    ElseIf OptionButton2.Value Then
        res = "Text example 2"
    Else
        res = "Nothing is selected"
    End If
    'write result in cell
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = res
    'close form
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Even simpler! This keeps my workbook a little more organized.